# google foo.bar max path algorithm puzzle optimization

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, dynamic-programming

I got a programming puzzle described as follows:

> ## Save Beta Rabbit
>
> Oh no! The mad Professor Boolean has trapped Beta Rabbit in an NxN
>   grid of rooms. In the center of each room (except for the top left
>   room) is a hungry zombie. In order to be freed, and to avoid being
>   eaten, Beta Rabbit must move through this grid and feed the zombies.
>
> Beta Rabbit starts at the top left room of the grid. For each room in
>   the grid, there is a door to the room above, below, left, and right.
>   There is no door in cases where there is no room in that direction.
>   However, the doors are locked in such a way that Beta Rabbit can only
>   ever move to the room below or to the right. Once Beta Rabbit enters a
>   room, the zombie immediately starts crawling towards him, and he must
>   feed the zombie until it is full to ward it off. Thankfully, Beta
>   Rabbit took a class about zombies and knows how many units of food
>   each zombie needs be full.
>
> To be freed, Beta Rabbit needs to make his way to the bottom right
>   room (which also has a hungry zombie) and have used most of the
>   limited food he has. He decides to take the path through the grid such
>   that he ends up with as little food as possible at the end.
>
> Write a function answer(food, grid) that returns the number of units
>   of food Beta Rabbit will have at the end, given that he takes a route
>   using up as much food as possible without him being eaten, and ends at
>   the bottom right room. If there does not exist a route in which Beta
>   Rabbit will not be eaten, then return -1.
>
> food is the amount of food Beta Rabbit starts with, and will be a
>   positive integer no larger than 200.
>
> grid will be a list of N elements. Each element of grid will itself be
>   a list of N integers each, denoting a single row of N rooms. The first
>   element of grid will be the list denoting the top row, the second
>   element will be the list denoting second row from the top, and so on
>   until the last element, which is the list denoting the bottom row. In
>   the list denoting a single row, the first element will be the amount
>   of food the zombie in the left-most room in that row needs, the second
>   element will be the amount the zombie in the room to its immediate
>   right needs and so on. The top left room will always contain the
>   integer 0, to indicate that there is no zombie there.
>
> The number of rows N will not exceed 20, and the amount of food each
>   zombie requires will be a positive integer not exceeding 10.
>
> ## Languages
>
> To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java
>   solution, edit solution.java
>
> ## Test cases
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) food = 7
>       (int) grid = [[0, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1]] Output:
>       (int) 0
>
> Inputs:
>       (int) food = 12
>       (int) grid = [[0, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1]] Output:
>       (int) 1

I came up with a solution but it is failing 2 out of 5 tests (specifically tests 3 and 5. Of course I have no clue what these tests do but my hunch is that it is an optimization issue. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on enhancing the code.

```
"""
This is a max cost path with a cap. The approach is to use recursion
And start from the end point and work our way back to the starting point
"""


def answer(food, grid):
    # Set coordinates to end point
    N = len(grid)
    x = N - 1
    y = N - 1
    def backtrack(f, x, y):
        #print 'food: %d, x: %d, y: %d'%(f, x, y)
        f -= grid[x][y]
        print 'food: %d, x: %d, y: %d'%(f, x, y)
        # This is our base case, reaching the starting point.
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            return f
        # If we run out of food, return -1
        elif f < 0:
            return -1
        # If we reach the left wall, the only way is up
        elif x == 0 and y > 0:
            return backtrack(f, x, y-1)
        # If we reach the top wall, the only way is left
        elif x > 0 and y == 0:
            return backtrack(f, x-1, y)
        # for each step, after we subtract current food from total food,
        # Subtract the amount in the left and top cells and pick the smallest
        # non-negative value. 
        elif (f - grid[x-1][y] < f - grid[x][y-1]) and (f - grid[x-1][y] >= 0):
            return backtrack(f, x-1, y)
        else:
            return backtrack(f, x, y-1)

    remainder = backtrack(food, x, y)
    return remainder
```

I timed it with the following inputs:

grid = [[0, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1]]
food = 12

The result is:

--- 7.58171081543e-05 seconds ---

Comment: Do you know if it is a performance issue (speed or memory) or if it is a correctness issue? Do you get the correct results?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not a correctness issue, I ran the two test examples in the description of the problem and got the same result. This is my 6th problem and I have run into several instances where the last two tests fail and then after improving the time comlexity it passes everything.

Comment: This code is broken, see my answer, it's not down to speed but to incorrect implementation.

Comment: See [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91593/11728).

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that @Mast, new poster here. I will answer myself with the revised code. I am not sure my upvotes count yet since I don't have the required reputation yet, correct?

Comment: @GarethRees, i came across that thread not too long ago but wanted to try to come up with a solution on my own.

Answer (score 2):

This code is broken.
If we look at the [test cases that are used](https://github.com/dlew/google-foobar/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/challenges/TestSaveBetaRabbit.java), and implement them in Python,
you should get something like:

```
import unittest

class TestAnswer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_tiny_grid(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, answer(0, [[0]]))

    def test_google_cases(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, answer(7, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(1, answer(12, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))

    def test_simple_grid(self):
        self.assertEqual(-1, answer(2, [
            [0, 2],
            [3, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(0, answer(3, [
            [0, 2],
            [3, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(0, answer(4, [
            [0, 2],
            [3, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(1, answer(5, [
            [0, 2],
            [3, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(2, answer(5, [
            [0, 2],
            [2, 1]
        ]))

    def test_some_other_things(self):
        # Tricky case; ensures that top row/left row only assume one direction of entry
        self.assertEqual(2, answer(9, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(189, answer(200, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(0, answer(4, [
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(0, answer(30, [
            [0, 7, 4, 3],
            [3, 5, 5, 3],
            [5, 2, 7, 9],
            [1, 9, 8, 4]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(0, answer(37, [
            [0, 7, 4, 3],
            [3, 5, 5, 3],
            [5, 2, 7, 9],
            [1, 9, 8, 4]
        ]))

    def test_not_enough_food(self):
        self.assertEqual(-1, answer(3, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))

        self.assertEqual(-1, answer(4, [
            [0, 7, 4, 3],
            [3, 5, 5, 3],
            [5, 2, 7, 9],
            [1, 9, 8, 4]
        ]))

unittest.main()
```

Your code fails to pass two of these tests.
Which are:

```
class TestAnswer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple_grid(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, answer(3, [
            [0, 2],
            [3, 1]
        ]))

    def test_some_other_things(self):
        # Tricky case; ensures that top row/left row only assume one direction of entry
        self.assertEqual(2, answer(9, [
            [0, 2, 5],
            [1, 1, 3],
            [2, 1, 1]
        ]))
```

Comment: Nice find! Are these the actual tests that are run by google when verifying the solution to this puzzle? Looks like I have some debugging to do. I better hurry up it's due tonight.

Comment: @TBadr It's from the src of the thing that you linked, so I'd assume so

Comment: I have addressed the failed test by adding additional checks for two scenarios. If we are at the last step (1,1) and going either up or left result in 0 remainder, then go ahead, otherwise default to the original logic. Of course now that I try to verify solution through foobar I am getting an http bad request error. This is third puzzle of level 3 with less than 9 hours to go. Arrrgghhh

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code to the following:

```
def answer(food, grid):
    # Set coordinates to end point
    # N = len(grid)
    x = len(grid) - 1
    y = len(grid) - 1
    def backtrack(f, x, y):
        #print 'food: %d, x: %d, y: %d'%(f, x, y)
        f -= grid[x][y]
        print 'food: %d, x: %d, y: %d'%(f, x, y)
        # This is our base case, reaching the starting point.
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            print 'case1: done'
            return f
        # If we run out of food, return -1
        elif f < 0:
            print 'case2: undoable'
            return -1
        # If we reach the left wall, the only way is up
        elif x == 0 and y > 0:
            print 'case3: Reached top wall, go left'
            return backtrack(f, x, y-1)
        # If we reach the top wall, the only way is left
        elif x > 0 and y == 0:
            print' case4: Reached left wall, go up'
            return backtrack(f, x-1, y)

        # If we are at the last step (1,1) and going up or left leaves us with 0, do it
        elif (f - grid[x-1][y] == 0 and (x==1 and y==1)):
            print' case5: Last step, go up'
            return backtrack(f, x-1, y)

        elif (f - grid[x][y-1] == 0 and (x==1 and y==1)):
            print' case6: Last step, go left'
            return backtrack(f, x, y-1)

        # for each step, after we subtract current food from total food,
        # Subtract the amount in the left and top cells and pick the smallest
        # non-negative value.
        elif (f - grid[x-1][y] < f - grid[x][y-1] and f - grid[x-1][y] > 0):
            print'case7: Not last step, go up'
            return backtrack(f, x-1, y)
        else:
            print 'case8: Not last step, go left'
            return backtrack(f, x, y-1)
            # return min(filter(lambda i: i >= 0, (backtrack(f, x-1, y), backtrack(f, x, y-1))))

    return backtrack(food, x, y)
```

This fixes the cases that I was failing but when i verify my solution through foobar it still says failing tests 3 and 5 out of 5.

Comment: hmmm, only fails one scenario: answer(30, [[0, 7, 4, 3], [3, 5, 5, 3], [5, 2, 7, 9], [1, 9, 8, 4]])